# How to keep some drawings and not others?

Tags: java, graphics

I couldn't find any other questions like this, but if someone finds a question like it, feel free to mark it as a duplicate.

I am wondering how to keep only some of the drawings that are on screen. As some preface, I am trying to make a small paint like program (I am making this with the Leap Motion). I want it so that if the Z if less than -80 then draw a line that stays on the screen (As if you were clicking the mouse) and if not, then don't draw a line, just show a 'cursor' (A little white dot). The method I am using to draw things to the screen is as follows:

```
protected void render() {
    BufferStrategy bStrategy = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bStrategy == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics graphics = bStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
    {
        Drawing.getInstance(graphics).drawBackground(Color.BLACK, getWidth(), getHeight());
        {
            List<Coordinate> list = Drawing.getInstance(graphics).drawColorBox(3, 25, 25, 0, 50, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.BLUE);
            List<Coordinate> listII = Drawing.getInstance(graphics).drawColorBox(3, 25, 25, 0, 25, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.RED);
            Drawing.getInstance(graphics).drawDot(loc.getX(), loc.getY(), 5, 5, currentColor);
            getCollision(list, Color.BLUE, graphics);
            getCollision(listII, Color.RED, graphics);
        }
    }
    graphics.dispose();
    bStrategy.show();
}
```

Drawing is another class that just deals with the drawing of items to the screen. If you need the class just ask.

Summary:
I want to draw some lines to the screen, but not others and want to be able to control which ones to draw and not to draw.

If this doesn't make sense just say and I will try and reword it. Any help is appreciated.
~Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making a `Line` class with an `isVisible` instance variable. Keep track of all the lines in an `ArrayList<Line>`, and then toggle them on or off with the `isVisible` variable.

Comment: I am quite new to this, so how would I go about doing this if I am drawing the lines through a set of points. My process of doing it before was to create a rectangle with the x and y that I got and a width of 5 for example. Then not refresh the background so that it would stay rendered. Sorry if this is a very basic question, but right now I feel clueless.

Comment: Each `Line` object would contain data for the start and end points, I guess. But I don't exactly get what you're asking here. Also, I don't believe I am familiar with the graphics libraries you are using.

Comment: I have figured it out, albeit strangely. I am using the Leap Motion (an awesome piece of technology) that creates a Vector with an XYZ. I can then do whatever I want with these. I created two line classes, Line and HiddenLine. HiddenLine will show a point and then remove the point after it whereas Line will just display all of the points. Thanks for the help!